# Coordinates of the incenter of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$A = (x_{1},y_{1})$, $B =(x_{2},y_{2})$, and $C = (x_{3},y_{3})$ are three (distinct) non-collinear points in the Cartesian plane, and $a = \left\vert \overline{BC} \right\vert$, $b = \left\vert \overline{AC} \right\vert$, and $c = \left\vert \overline{AB} \right\vert$. The incenter of the triangle is
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{ax_{1} + bx_{2} + cx_{3}}{a + b + c} , \ \frac{ay_{1} + by_{2} + cy_{3}}{a + b + c}\right) .
\end{equation*}

The $x$-coordinate of the incenter is a "weighted average" of the $x$-coordinates of the vertices of the given triangle, and the $y$-coordinate of the incenter is the same "weighted average" of the $y$-coordinates of the same vertices. I am requesting an explanation for this statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bisector of angle $A$ intersects side $BC$ at a point $A'$, and according to [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) we have: $A'B:A'C=c:b$. It follows that $A'$ is a weighted average of
$B$ and $C$, with weights given by the lengths of the opposite sides:
$$
A'={b\over b+c}B+{c\over b+c}C,
$$
and of course we have analogous expressions for the similarly defined points $B'$ and $C'$.

The incenter $I$ of $ABC$ is the intersection of $AA'$, $BB'$ and $CC'$. It is then hardly surprising that it turns out to be the weighted average of $A$, $B$ and $C$. For instance: as $I$ belongs to segment $AA'$ we can write:
$$
I=(1-t)A+tA'=(1-t)A+{tb\over b+c}B+{tc\over b+c}C,
$$
for some $t\in[0,1]$. But the expression for $I$ must be symmetric when exchanging $A$, $B$, $C$ among them, and it is easy to verify that $t={b+c\over a+b+c}$ does the trick, leading to your formula for $I$:
$$
I={a\over a+b+c}A+{b\over a+b+c}B+{c\over a+b+c}C.
$$

Comment: Very good. I understand that the Angle-Bisector Theorem yields coordinates of the endpoints of the angle bisectors on the sides of the triangles that are certain weighted averages - with weights equal to the lengths of two sides of the given triangle.

Comment: It is merely a tedious computation to verify that the given incenter is a point on all three angle bisectors.

Comment: For example, if $\overline{AA_{1}}$ is not a vertical line, ...

Comment: ... $m_{A} = \frac{b(y_{2} - y_{1}) + c(y_{3} - y_{1})}{b(x_{2} - x_{1}) + c(x_{3} - x_{1})}$ ...

Comment: ... is the slope of it, ...

Comment: ... $y = m_{A}(x - x_{1}) + y_{1}$ is an equation for the line through $\overline{AA_{1}}$, ...

Comment: ... and  the given incenter is a point on it.

Comment: That the incenter is the intersection of the angle bisectors immediately follows from its definition, so I don't understand your comment. I'll add some more to better explain why the incenter is given by your formula.

Comment: My comments are intended to help others reading this post. There is still some computations to perform to get the coordinates of the incenter. I furnished some of them.

Comment: All right then. However I think the vector method I added to my answer is faster.